# Specman: How to determine if list has default size (using reflection)?

Tags: reflection, specman

I want to use the reflection features to determine if list has default size.

lets say I declared those lists:

```
a    : list of int;
b[3] : list of int;
```

then I want to create a function `is_default_sized()` and get:

`is_default_sized(a)` will return false, and `is_default_sized(b)` will return true.

Note: I didn't find such method in `rf_field`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method:

> rf_field.get_declared_list_size()

It will return the declared size if any, or UNDEF if no default size was declared.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using v12, and that method is new in v13